How to see output of the typescript compile log in vscode
I want to print the output of the process that vscode's default typescript compiles .ts files. Like I excute the command 'node ./node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js --watch --extendedDiagnostics' in terminal. And how should I configure vscode?
I try to set the "typescript.tsserver.watchOptions" and "typescript.tsserver.log", but it doesn't work. The output don't print the process that vscode's typescript sompiles .ts files.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
